# R glmnet package: why is elasticnet parametrized like that?

Tags: r, glmnet, elastic-net

The documentation for `glmnet` in `R` [here](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html) states that it solves the following minimization problem:

[image: glmnet-minimization-constraint]

Why did the authors choose to parametrize $\alpha$ in such a way that $\alpha=\frac{1}{3}$ corresponds to the elastic-net parameter that will lend equal weight to the $L_1$ and $L_2$ parameter, rather than the seemingly natural choice of $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$? Is there a reason that they added the extra factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ to the $L_2$ penalty?